# Decoding an array of objects with nested heterogeneous child objects

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decodable

An example of the response from the server is below.

The list consists of elements that have heterogeneous substructures in the `info` fields. Each of them contains 3 fields with the same types, but they have different keys.

I don't know how to decode this, I haven't encountered such a problem so far. I can't find an example on the Internet that fits this case.

I wanted to decode the enum `type` at the beginning and select the appropriate `info` structure based on it, but it doesn't work.

I would very much appreciate your help.

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "type":"league",
      "info":{
        "name":"NBA",
        "sport":"Basketball",
        "website":"https://nba.com/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"player",
      "info":{
        "name":"Kawhi Leonard",
        "position":"Small Forward",
        "picture":"https://i.ibb.co/b5sGk6L/40a233a203be2a30e6d50501a73d3a0a8ccc131fv2-128.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"team",
      "info":{
        "name":"Los Angeles Clippers",
        "state":"California",
        "logo":"https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/LA_Clippers_logo_logotype_emblem.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I recommend an enum with associated types like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461042/swift-json-decoder-different-types/59461570#59461570)

Comment: Are you able to know what are _all_ possible keys? If yes, then you can declare all of them as optionals.

Comment: @AhmadF I know all the types, but declaring all the fields as optionals is not an option - the codebase would grow too fast.

Comment: @vadian, I followed your advice and the following code snippet was created: https://pastebin.com/S3uSXgtU
Didn't the 2 enums make a mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code on pastebin is too complicated, I mean this

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "data":[
    {
      "type":"league",
      "info":{
        "name":"NBA",
        "sport":"Basketball",
        "website":"https://nba.com/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"player",
      "info":{
        "name":"Kawhi Leonard",
        "position":"Small Forward",
        "picture":"https://i.ibb.co/b5sGk6L/40a233a203be2a30e6d50501a73d3a0a8ccc131fv2-128.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"team",
      "info":{
        "name":"Los Angeles Clippers",
        "state":"California",
        "logo":"https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/LA_Clippers_logo_logotype_emblem.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
"""

struct Response: Decodable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct League: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sport: String
    let website: URL
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let name: String
    let position: String
    let picture: URL
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let name: String
    let state: String
    let logo: URL
}

enum Datum: Decodable {
    case league(League)
    case player(Player)
    case team(Team)
    
    enum DatumType: String, Decodable {
        case league
        case player
        case team
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case type, info }
 
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(DatumType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .league:
            let item = try container.decode(League.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .league(item)
        case .player:
            let item = try container.decode(Player.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .player(item)
        case .team:
            let item = try container.decode(Team.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .team(item)
        }
    }
}

do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    let data = response.data
    print(data)
//    receivedData.forEach { (datum) in
//        let cell = Cell()
//        cell.configure(with: datum.info.rowData)
//        cells.append(cell)
//    }
//    cells.forEach({ print($0.title, $0.subtitle) })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In the cell switch on the type

```
switch datum {
    case .league(let league): // so something with league
    case .player(let player): // so something with player
    case .team(let team): // so something with team
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @vadian!
Could you please tell me how to put these `datum` nested values inside a following structure snippet?
https://pastebin.com/Lc1u3aQ2

I want to have a list of `Items` where `Item<Displayable>`, but I am afraid this is not possible, because only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols.

Comment: An answer depends on the context the structs are used in. Please ask a new question and provide more information. And please add relevant code directly to the question as text rather than as external link.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228972/cannot-map-protocol-compliant-elements-to-generic-elements