# Cannot map protocol compliant elements to generic elements

Tags: swift, generics, mapping, protocols, decodable

As you can see below, I downloaded an array of structures containing heterogeneous objects that were decoded into enums containing nested objects.

I would now like to put said objects into a generic Model structure, but the compiler won't allow this - the error is described below in the code comment. I am relatively new to programming in Swift, I would appreciate your help.

```
import Foundation

let jsonString = """
{
  "data":[
    {
      "type":"league",
      "info":{
        "name":"NBA",
        "sport":"Basketball",
        "website":"https://nba.com/"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"player",
      "info":{
        "name":"Kawhi Leonard",
        "position":"Small Forward",
        "picture":"https://i.ibb.co/b5sGk6L/40a233a203be2a30e6d50501a73d3a0a8ccc131fv2-128.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "type":"team",
      "info":{
        "name":"Los Angeles Clippers",
        "state":"California",
        "logo":"https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/LA_Clippers_logo_logotype_emblem.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
"""

struct Response: Decodable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct League: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sport: String
    let website: URL
}

extension League: Displayable {
    var text: String { name }
    var image: URL { website }
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let name: String
    let position: String
    let picture: URL
}

extension Player: Displayable {
    var text: String { name }
    var image: URL { picture }
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let name: String
    let state: String
    let logo: URL
}

extension Team: Displayable {
    var text: String { name }
    var image: URL { logo }
}

enum Datum: Decodable {
    case league(League)
    case player(Player)
    case team(Team)
    
    enum DatumType: String, Decodable {
        case league
        case player
        case team
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case type, info }
 
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(DatumType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .league:
            let item = try container.decode(League.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .league(item)
        case .player:
            let item = try container.decode(Player.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .player(item)
        case .team:
            let item = try container.decode(Team.self, forKey: .info)
            self = .team(item)
        }
    }
}

protocol Displayable {
    var text: String { get }
    var image: URL { get }
}
 
struct Model<T: Displayable> {
    let text: String
    let image: URL
    
    init(item: T) {
        self.text = item.text
        self.image = item.image
    }
}

do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    let items = response.data
    let models = items.map { (item) -> Model<Displayable> in // error: only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        switch item {
        case .league(let league):
            return Model(item: league)
        case .player(let player):
            return Model(item: player)
        case .team(let team):
            return Model(item: team)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need generics here.

Change Model to accept any type that conforms to Displayable in the init

```
struct Model {
    let text: String
    let image: URL

    init(item: Displayable) {
        self.text = item.text
        self.image = item.image
    }
}
```

and then change the closure to return Model

```
let models = items.map { (item) -> Model in
```

---

If you want to keep your Model struct generic then you need to change the `map` call to

```
let models: [Any] = items.map { item -> Any in
    switch item {
    case .league(let league):
        return Model(item: league)
    case .player(let player):
        return Model(item: player)
    case .team(let team):
        return Model(item: team)
    }
}
```

This will give the following output when conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
extension Model: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "\(text) type:\(type(of: self))"
    }
}

print(models)
```

> [NBA type:Model<League>, Kawhi Leonard type:Model<Player>, Los Angeles Clippers type:Model<Team>]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already came up with that idea too.
The generic type in this case is required.

Comment: @s_chaterera Required? What is your end-goal with this, do you really want to have an array of type [Any] that holds the model objects?

Comment: My goal is to transform the resulting JSON into a collection of Model<T> objects, where T is a team, player or league. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: @s_chaterera Yes but you are aware that a Model<Team> object and a Model<Player> object for instance are 2 completely different types so the only way to have them in an array is to have an array of type [Any] which isn't that useful.

Comment: @s_chaterera I have included a solution for using a generic Model struct

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in `name` and the key representing the URL parse the JSON directly into `Model` by using `nestedContainer` this way

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let data: [Model]
}

struct Model: Decodable {
     let name: String
     let image: URL
    
    enum DatumType: String, Decodable {
        case league
        case player
        case team
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case type, info }
    private enum CodingSubKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, website, picture, logo }
 
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(DatumType.self, forKey: .type)
        
        let subContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingSubKeys.self, forKey: .info)
        self.name = try subContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        
        let urlKey : CodingSubKeys
        switch type {
            case .league: urlKey = .website
            case .player: urlKey = .picture
            case .team: urlKey = .logo
        }
        self.image = try subContainer.decode(URL.self, forKey: urlKey)
    }
}

do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    let data = response.data
    print(data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @vadian. I was thinking about parsing JSON directly into the Model, but in this case another way is required. The number of keys may grow over time. I'm looking for a solution that uses generic types, even if it would require changing the decoding method (which unfortunately currently seems like overkill to me).

Comment: If *the number of keys may grow over time* you have to adjust the model especially the `Datum` enum anyway. There is no benefit of generics or protocols because you **always** have  to convert a concrete type to a generic or protocol type somewhere.